# mysql check no records within 3 months with group limit by 1 show the last transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to have a mysql query that generates data without records 3 months period. Display the latest transaction group by name limit by 1.

```
**Sample data (March to May)**

Name    Date of Transaction 
Robert     2014-03-03
Angel      2014-02-25
Robert     2014-06-03
Daniel     2014-03-11
Angel      2014-05-31
Christine  2014-01-31
Henry      2014-05-05
Henry      2014-06-01
Nicole     2014-03-25

**It should display:**

Name    Date of Transaction 
Daniel     2014-03-11
Nicole     2014-03-25
Angel      2014-05-31
Henry      2014-06-01
Robert     2014-06-03
```

Is this possible? Here is my query but not working

```
SELECT *
FROM <tablename>
WHERE date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY date
DESC
```

**EDIT**

How about without the no records within 3 months?

```
Name    Date of Transaction 
Christine  2014-01-31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use group by you can only display columns in your group by clause unless using an aggregate function.  Does this help?

```
SELECT name, max(dtTransaction)
FROM <tablename>
WHERE date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
GROUP BY name
```

Use max to get the latest date.

Comment: thank you! how about no records within 3 months? please check the EDIT portion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Date of Transaction)
FROM <tablename>
WHERE date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: thank you! how about no records within 3 months? please check the EDIT portion.

Comment: Then you have to remove your 3 months interval cond.

Comment: No Sir i need the condition to check whether there is no transaction made within those 3 months period

Comment: Can you plz elaborate what exact result you want.

Comment: hi @Ankit, on the example above i want to display the record Christine on the list which do not range to 3 months (2014-01-31)